# Add values from multiple arrayLists in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist

I need to add decimal numbers held in the last index of arraylists, to a decimal subtotal, for Windows Forms. My processOrder MenuItem gives error:

> subList1 does not exist in the current context.

But subLists are ok in my AddtoCart MenuItem method when using .Add. If I enter 
`subtotal = (subList1.RemoveAt(3) + subList2.RemoveAt(3));` in AddtoCart() as a test the error is:

> cannot use + operator with operands of type void and void.

I do not want to use another class and getters. Doesn't matter if values are removed, I just need to obtain the values and add them for my solution to work.

Comment: You should really start formatting your question better. Also, try to have a little bit more logic on what you are asking. I for one, haven't understood a thing

Comment: Could you show the code generating the array list? Also, since .NET 2 `ArrayList` is deprecated. Use `List<T>` instead (yes, that requires a class. C# is OOP).

Comment: BTW `RemoveAt` is for removing and not reading values.

Answer (score 3):

The `RemoveAt()` function doesn't return the value. It just removes it and throws it away. Instead, this would work:

```
subtotal = ((decimal)subList1[subList1.Count-1]) + (decimal)subList2.[subList2.Count - 1];
```

Even better, you can get rid of that ugly casting if you use a simple `List<decimal>` instead of an ArrayList. There's really no good reason to *ever* use an ArrayList anymore.

```
subtotal = subList1[subList.Count - 1] + subList2[subList2.Count - 1];
```

If you're using a recent version of Visual Studio you can simplify the code further:

```
subtotal = subList1.Last() + subList2.Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely practice some more C# and read about collections. You're not looking for `RemoveAt()` as it simply removes an item from a collection (`ArrayList` in this case), and is a void method, which has no return value.

What you need is `subtotal = subList1[3] + subList2[3]`.

Comment: Let me re-state: I'm working in Windows Forms. I'm trying to add the numbers from the last element of my arraylists. nXu corrected my syntax but subtotal = ((decimal)subList1[2] + subList2[2] .... (decimal)subList5[2]); generates error 'Argument out of range exception'.

Answer (score 0):

Let me re-state for barca_d: I'm working in Windows Forms. I'm trying to add the numbers from the last element of my arraylists. nXu corrected my syntax but                                                                            subtotal = ((decimal)subList1[2] + subList2[2] .... (decimal)subList5[2]); generates error 'Argument out of range exception'. From what I understand, before input, the index value is -1, afterwards value must be 0-2.

From what I can find, List can only use one type. Hence, using arraylist. Teacher has only gone over arrays but says arraylists are better. We haven't gone over hashtable and other collections yet. Arraylists were generated like this:   private ArrayList subList1 = new ArrayList(3);

Can List<> use multiple types somehow? My counter for AddtoCart Menu Item must not be working. 
Solution was to initialize arraylist elements to null.

Thank you for the feedback & tips.